# javascript getElementByTagname

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

Is there code to fetch the meta data information of other websites such as title,keyword using javascript ?
document.getElementById will help to fetch the information of current document.Likewise is there a code to fetch information of other than current document.

Comment: You cannot find information other than current document because you are accessing DOM component which is always related with current document.But you can able to fetch the  attributes like 'title'.

Comment: suppose now i am in www.abb.com and i want to get meta description of some other website say www.ccc.com .How i can do with the javascript?

Comment: you cannot do this. Its not possible.

Comment: suppose if it is the case with documents?then how i can do?

Comment: java script is client side scripting. You cannot access any information for server side. an Ajax call is provided by java script for that, in case you want to access server side information.

Comment: thank you.if you have php /ajax code related to it can u provide?

Comment: Go to www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp  and  
api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could use the [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) method to extract this information from the current document:

```
​alert(document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML);​
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A3szU/).

As far as *other* web sites are concerned, well, as you know the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction prevents you from retrieving their contents using AJAX. But if you have a server side script on your domain that will retrieve the HTML contents of those remote sites you could perfectly fine send an AJAX request to your script and in the success callback parse the HTML and retrieve the information you are interested in (meta, title, ...). But since you've already setup a server side script to retrieve the remote contents it could directly be this server side script that parses the remote HTML and returns you the required information.

Comment: You can't do this with javascript only. The same origin policy restriction that's built into the browsers prevents you from retrieving the contents of remote domains. You will have to setup a server side script on your domain that will serve as a bridge, as explained in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Didn't you read my answer? I repeat: you setup a server side script on your domain that will retrieve the remote page HTML. Then you trigger an AJAX request to your server side script. You forget about using javascript to retrieve remote domain HTML because this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, you can use PHP or any other server side language you wish. Here's an example with PHP: http://www.internoetics.com/2010/01/08/retrieve-data-from-a-remote-webpage/